# How do I write my own chainable iterator function in Rust?

Tags: rust, iterator

Let's say I want to double each value in an iterator of numbers. I could do this:

```
vec![1, 2, 3]
    .into_iter()
    .map(|x| x * 2)
    .for_each(|x| println!("{}", x)); //Prints 2, 4, 6.
```

To get cleaner code, I would prefer to do this:

```
vec![1, 2, 3]
    .into_iter()
    .double() //I need to implement this.
    .for_each(|x| println!("{}", x));
```

How do I write my own chainable iterator function, like `double` in this example? I guess I will have to create an interface and implement it for Iterator? There are a lot of types to get right, so a working solution for this silly example would be helpful.

Comment: The best way to learn this is to look in the source for any of the built-in iterator functions. For example [enumerate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/iterator.rs.html#783-785) is a simple one. The implementation of the struct is [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/mod.rs.html#1661-1688). Note that this implementation overrides a lot of methods, but you only need to define `next`.

Comment: This is a good thing to learn, but I would argue that this is not "cleaner" in this particular case. It will introduce a lot of code which is not really necessary compared to just using `map` as intended.

Comment: @E4_net_or_something_like_that Thanks for the links. I agree that it is not cleaner in this simple case, but I needed a simple example so as not to make the question to broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to create a new-type to implement your iterator. The simplest way is to wrap a iterator of the type you want to target:

```
struct Double<T: ?Sized> {
    inner: T,
}
```

Now you just implement the `Iterator` trait for this type if the innert type `T` is of the correct type. Something like:

```
impl<T> Iterator for Double<T>
where T: Iterator<Item = i32> {
    type Item = i32;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
        self.inner.next().map(|x| 2*x)
    }
}
```

And that's it! You just need to add a `Double` constructor. The most ergonomic solution is to extend `Iterator`. Something like this:

```
trait Doubler : Iterator<Item = i32> {
    fn into_double(self) -> Double<Self>;
}

impl<T> Doubler for T
where T: Iterator<Item = i32> {
    fn into_double(self) -> Double<Self> {
        Double { inner: self }
    }
}
```

An example of usage ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e6118b6cbca81909749d657bf1f8df88)):

```
fn main() {
    vec![1, 2, 3]
        .into_iter()
        .into_double()
        .for_each(|x| println!("{}", x));
}
```

Comment: Please do not answer duplicates; it makes maintaining an up-to-date knowledge base much harder.